# Producing a PDF with clickable chart

Tags: diagrams, links

Greetings.

John Cook provides a [clickable chart](http://www.johndcook.com/distribution_chart.html) of probability distributions with different interconnections. Every node is linked to definition and every arrow is linked to a brief description of interconnection.

I am interested in producing a PDF with analogous functionality.
I. e., I'd like to have a chart with arrows interlinked with various (text) definitions and descriptions.

Is it possible with LaTeX/ConTeXt/whatever?

Answer (score 7):

With Tikz package, it is possible to have nodes connected with definitions, but I cannot find way how to connect arrows with definitions.

So this is only partial answer to your question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\glsenablehyper
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,chains, positioning}
\tikzset{clickable/.style={draw, rectangle,rounded corners, inner sep = 2pt,fill= blue!20}}
\tikzaddtikzonlycommandshortcutdef{\clickable}{\node[clickable]}
\begin{document}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{geometric}{
   name={geometric}
  ,description={$f(x) = p (1-p)^x$ for non-negative integers $x$.}
}
\newglossaryentry{discrete}{
   name={Discrete uniform}
  ,description={$(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ for $x = 1, 2, ..., n$}
}
\newglossaryentry{negative}{
   name={Negative binomial}
  ,description={$f(x) = C(r + x - 1, x) p^r(1-p)^x$ for non-negative integers $x$}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clickable  (or) {\gls{geometric}} edge [loop right, ->] (or);
\clickable [below of=or] (bn) {\gls{discrete}} edge [dashed,<-] (or);
\clickable [right= 0.5cm of bn] (oo) {\gls{negative}} edge [<->] (bn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: diagram with links to glossary]
Glossary entries are defined with `\newglossaryentry` macro. For example:

```
\newglossaryentry{discrete}{
       name={Discrete uniform}
      ,description={$(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ for $x = 1, 2, ..., n$}
    }
```

`discrete` is the name you link to in your diagram, `name` is glossary heading.

To get the glossary list, you have to after you compile your document, run script `makeglossaries nameofthedocumentwithoutextension`.

You can refer to your glossary entries with macro `\gls{}`, for example, command `\gls{discrete}` will print *Discrete uniform*.

To learn about tikz, run command `texdoc tikz` in your shell. Just some notes about my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clickable  (or) {\gls{geometric}} edge [loop right, ->] (or);
\clickable [below of=or] (bn) {\gls{discrete}} edge [dashed,<-] (or);
\clickable [right= 0.5cm of bn] (oo) {\gls{negative}} edge [<->] (bn);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Our diagram is defined in `tikzpicture` environment. Macro `\clickable` is shortcut for `\node [clickable]`. In curly braces is text for label, because we are referring to the glossary entry, we call `\gls` macro. `(or)` is name of the node, it is used for referencing to the node from the other nodes. it is useful for placing the other nodes (`below of=or`) and for the arrows. `edge` is used for definition of the arrow. in `[]` brackets we set its style.

Comment: +1 for the use of `\tikzaddtikzonlycommandshortcutdef`!